# Custom Wordpress Widget with media upload button inserting the same image on every widget

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, widget

I'm a noob making my own custom widgets, and I wanted to make a custom widget to display featured services of a website including a image, title, description, and a link button. I looked a lot on stackoverflow and I end up having something almost working. The problem is that the media button works, the field works, but when I click "use this image", it puts the same image url on every input it finds (inside widgets desktop) with the class "image1", so every widget has the same image.

I would really appreciate if somebody could help me fix it. Sorry in advance for the spanish words, but them are not used in anything related to the actions I'm trying to fix. Here goes the functions.php code I have:

```
// START CUSTOM WIDGET
class services_widget extends WP_Widget {

    // Create Widget
    function services_widget() {
        parent::WP_Widget(false, $name = 'Servicios Destacados - Widget', array('description' => 'Widget para mostrar servicios destacados en la página principal'));
    }

    // Widget Content
    function widget($args, $instance) { 
        extract( $args );
        $photo = $instance['photo'];
        $titulo = $instance['titulo'];
        $descripcion = $instance['descripcion'];
        $enlace = strip_tags($instance['enlace']);
        $textoenlace = strip_tags($instance['textoenlace']);

        ?>

            <div class="servicio-destacado <?php echo $this->id; ?>">
                <div class="servicio-imagen" style="background-color:#eaeaea;background-image: url('<?php echo $photo; ?>');"></div>
                <div class="titulo"><?php echo $titulo; ?></div>
                <div class="line"></div>
                <div class="descripcion"><?php echo $descripcion; ?></div>
                <a href="<?php echo $enlace; ?>" class="enlace boton"><?php echo $textoenlace; ?></a>
            </div>

        <?php
     }


    // If widget content needs a form
    function form($instance) {
        //widgetform in backend
        $photo = $instance['photo'];
        $titulo = $instance['titulo'];
        $descripcion = $instance['descripcion'];
        $enlace = strip_tags($instance['enlace']);
        $textoenlace = strip_tags($instance['textoenlace']);
        ?>
        <div class="servicio-widget">
            <p>
                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('photo'); ?>"><strong>Imagen</strong>: </label>
                <input class="widefat image1" type="text" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('photo'); ?>" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('photo'); ?>" value="<?php echo attribute_escape($photo) ;?>">
            </p>
            <p>
                <button class="image_upload1">Seleccionar o cambiar imagen</button>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('titulo'); ?>"><strong>Título</strong>: </label>
                <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('titulo'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('titulo'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo attribute_escape($titulo); ?>" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('descripcion'); ?>"><strong>Descripción</strong>: </label>
                <textarea class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('descripcion'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('descripcion'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo attribute_escape($descripcion); ?>"><?php echo attribute_escape($descripcion); ?></textarea>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('textoenlace'); ?>"><strong>Texto del botón</strong>: </label>
                <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('textoenlace'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('textoenlace'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo attribute_escape($textoenlace); ?>" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('enlace'); ?>"><strong>Enlace</strong>: </label>
                <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('enlace'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('enlace'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo attribute_escape($enlace); ?>" />
            </p>
        </div>

        <?php       
    }

    // Update and save the widget
   public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
   $instance = array();
   $instance['photo'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['photo'] ) ) ? $new_instance['photo'] : '';

   return $instance;
}

}
register_widget('services_widget');
/*
photo upload option in widget
*/

function photo_upload_option($hook) {

    if( $hook != 'widgets.php' ) 
        return;

    //enque Javasript Media API
    wp_enqueue_media();

    wp_enqueue_script( 'uploadphoto', get_template_directory_uri() . '/upload_image.js', array('jquery') );

}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'photo_upload_option'); 
// END CUSTOM WIDGET
```

This is the code of upload_image.js:

```
jQuery(function($){

  // Set all variables to be used in scope
  var frame,
      addImgLink = $('.image_upload1'),
      imgIdInput = $('.image1');

  // ADD IMAGE LINK
  addImgLink.on( 'click', function( event ){

    event.preventDefault();

    // If the media frame already exists, reopen it.
    if ( frame ) {
      frame.open();
      return;
    }

    // Create a new media frame
    frame = wp.media({
      title: 'Select or Upload Image',
      button: {
        text: 'Use this Image'
      },
      multiple: false  // Set to true to allow multiple files to be selected
    });


    // When an image is selected in the media frame...
    frame.on( 'select', function() {

      // Get media attachment details from the frame state
      var attachment = frame.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();

      // Send the attachment URL to our custom image input field.
      //imgContainer.append( '<img src="'+attachment.url+'" alt="" style="max-width:100%;"/>' );

      // Send the attachment url to our input field
      imgIdInput.val( attachment.url );
    });

    // Finally, open the modal on click
    frame.open();
  });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is complete code for create image uploader in widget

function.php

```
<?php

// Register sidebar
if (function_exists('register_sidebar')) {
    register_sidebar(
        array(
        'name' => 'Left Sidebar',
        'id' => 'left-sidebar',
        'description' => 'Widget Area',
        'before_widget' => '<div id="one" class="two">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        )
    );
}

// Register widget
add_action('widgets_init', 'ctUp_ads_widget');
function ctUp_ads_widget() {
    register_widget( 'ctUp_ads' );
}

// Enqueue additional admin scripts
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'ctup_wdscript');
function ctup_wdscript() {
    wp_enqueue_media();
    wp_enqueue_script('ads_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/widget.js', false, '1.0.0', true);
}

// Widget
class ctUp_ads extends WP_Widget {

    function ctUp_ads() {
        $widget_ops = array('classname' => 'ctUp-ads');
        $this->WP_Widget('ctUp-ads-widget', 'EOTW', $widget_ops);
    }

    function widget($args, $instance) {
        echo $before_widget;
?>

    <h1><?php echo apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['text'] ); ?></h1>
    <img src="<?php echo esc_url($instance['image_uri']); ?>" />

<?php
        echo $after_widget;

    }

    function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
        $instance = $old_instance;
        $instance['text'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['text'] );
        $instance['image_uri'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['image_uri'] );
        return $instance;
    }

    function form($instance) {
?>

    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('text'); ?>">Text</label><br />
        <input type="text" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('text'); ?>" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('text'); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['text']; ?>" class="widefat" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="<?= $this->get_field_id( 'image_uri' ); ?>">Image</label>
        <img class="<?= $this->id ?>_img" src="<?= (!empty($instance['image_uri'])) ? $instance['image_uri'] : ''; ?>" style="margin:0;padding:0;max-width:100%;display:block"/>
        <input type="text" class="widefat <?= $this->id ?>_url" name="<?= $this->get_field_name( 'image_uri' ); ?>" value="<?= $instance['image_uri']; ?>" style="margin-top:5px;" />
        <input type="button" id="<?= $this->id ?>" class="button button-primary js_custom_upload_media" value="Upload Image" style="margin-top:5px;" />
    </p>

<?php
    }
}
```

JavaScript Button upload

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  function media_upload(button_selector) {
    var _custom_media = true,
        _orig_send_attachment = wp.media.editor.send.attachment;
    $('body').on('click', button_selector, function () {
      var button_id = $(this).attr('id');
      wp.media.editor.send.attachment = function (props, attachment) {
        if (_custom_media) {
          $('.' + button_id + '_img').attr('src', attachment.url);
          $('.' + button_id + '_url').val(attachment.url);
        } else {
          return _orig_send_attachment.apply($('#' + button_id), [props, attachment]);
        }
      }
      wp.media.editor.open($('#' + button_id));
      return false;
    });
  }
  media_upload('.js_custom_upload_media');
});
```

View File where you want to display this file:

```
if ( is_active_sidebar('left-sidebar') ) {
    dynamic_sidebar('left-sidebar');
}
```